# can't run flask from .sh file in windows

Tags: windows, flask

i have this code to run my flask app it is located in my backend folder but the main.py is in another directory level

```
#!/bin/bash
set FLASK_APP=src/main
#source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
flask run -h 0.0.0.0

/bin/bash
```

this is my tree from my backend directory

[image]

error:

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.

Comment: CMD tag is the Windows command line interface.

Comment: I know, I don't understand your answer

Comment: You have tagged you question with CMD. CMD is a Windows tag and we don't want to see Bash questions.